# use a href as a var in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors

I have a function that requires some vars being appended to a div. One of the vars is an a href link with onclick. How do I format the link to work in the var within the function? The below is not working.

What the whole purpose of this is is to

- evaluate a block of text. Count and limit the display to 200 characters
- insert an ahref link with onclick before the remainder of the text
- throw a span around the remainder of the text
- after the link insert another ahref link within the span, right before the closing span tag
- and insert all of this modified content in a div

I've taken two snippets of code

- 1)  trim text, and wrap in span [jquery limit text by length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723650/jquery-limit-text-by-length)
- 2)  show on click, hide on click http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2007/show-and-hide-elements-with-javascript

and am trying to mash them together to come up with what I need. Each snippet works on its own.

This is the code as I have it now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    function hideStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
$(function() {
    var limit = 200;
    var chars = $("#myDiv").text(); 
    if (chars.length > limit) {
        var visiblePart = $("<div> "+ chars.substr(0, limit-1) + "</div>");
        var readMore = $(<a href="#" onclick="showStuff('answer1'); return false;">open</a>);      
        var hiddenPart = $("<span id='answer1' style='display: none;'> " + chars.substr(limit-1)  + "</span>");
        var readLess = $(<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"hideStuff('answer1'); return false;\">close</a>); 
        });

        $("#myDiv").empty()
            .append(visiblePart)
            .append(readMore)
            .append(hiddenPart)
            .append(readLess);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Felix's version above so both links weren't showing at the same time:

http://jsfiddle.net/cXw5D/4/

EDIT:

Cleaned up syntax one last time:

http://jsfiddle.net/cXw5D/5/

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery, then use it consistently. The biggest error you have above is that the HTML is not inside strings, hence you will get a syntax error in JavaScript.

Here is a slightly improved version:

```
$(function() {
    var limit = 200;
    var chars = $('#myDiv').text(); 
    if (chars.length > limit) {
        var visiblePart = $('<div />').text(chars.substr(0, limit-1));
        var readMore = $('<a />', {
             href: '#',
             click: function() {
                 hiddenPart.show();
                 return false;
             },
             text: 'open'
        });      
        var hiddenPart = $('<span />', {text: chars.substr(limit-1)}).hide();
        var readLess = $('<a />', {
             href: '#',
             click: function() {
                 hiddenPart.hide();
                 return false;
             },
             text: 'close'
        });  

        $('#myDiv').empty()
            .append(visiblePart)
            .append(readMore)
            .append(hiddenPart)
            .append(readLess);
    }
});
```

It is still far from perfect but might give you a start: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/cXw5D/

Comment: +1, but fingering consistency and then alternating ' or " isn't practicing what you preach ;)

Comment: @Marc: True :) (for my defense: it's partly copy and paste :o)) ... *fixed ;)*.