# Wordpress ellipsis on title

Tags: php, wordpress, ellipsis

I tried doing the same procedure on this post :[Wordpress Titles: If Longer Than 50 Characters, Show Ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617769/wordpress-titles-if-longer-than-50-characters-show-ellipsis)

but no luck at all , can you tell what did i do wrong?

here's my snippet

```
function wpfp_list_most_favorited($limit=5) {
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT post_id, meta_value, post_status FROM $wpdb->postmeta";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON post_id=$wpdb->posts.ID";
$query .= " WHERE post_status='publish' AND meta_key='".WPFP_META_KEY."' AND meta_value > 0 ORDER BY ROUND(meta_value) DESC LIMIT 0, $limit";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
if ($results) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($results as $o):
        $p = get_post($o->post_id);
        $post = mb_strimwidth($p, 0, 20, '...');
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($o->post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'>" . $post->post_id . "</a> ($o->meta_value)";
        echo "</li>";
    endforeach;
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

}

Comment: `mb_strimwidth()` is a string function, you're applying it to an object

Comment: so how should it be done? can i do this?      echo "<a href='".get_permalink($o->post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'>" . mb_strimwidth($p, 0, 20, '...') . "</a> ($o->meta_value)";

Comment: Well your link indicates you want to echo the post id? so you probably want to remove `$post->post_id` and replace it with  `mb_strimwidth($p->post_title,0,20,'...')`

Comment: still not working , i wonder why :(

Answer (score 0):

I've the following function for myself it works perfectly.

**At the top of my functions.php file I use the following code:**

```
function truncate($text, $chars = 25) {
   $text = $text." ";
   $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
   $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
   $text = $text."...";
   return $text;
}
```

**After that you can use it anywhere you want like:**

```
<?php echo truncate($post->post_title, 50); ?>
OR 
<?php echo "<a href='".get_permalink($o->post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'>" . truncate($post->post_title,50) . "</a> ($o->meta_value)"; ?>
```