# Is it possible to have text-overflow: ellipsis without white-space: nowrap?

Tags: css, typography

It seems that `text-overflow: ellipsis` is dependent on `white-space: nowrap`.  The problem with this is that it limits the text to one line.  However, what if I need to have 4 lines, and the ellipsis on the last line in the case of overflow?

What it's currently doing...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
```

What I want...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing el-
it, sed do eiusmod tempor  
incididunt ut labore et ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use text-overflow:ellipsis without the white-space:nowrap rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-without-the-white-spacenowrap-rule)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the behavior you are seeing is correct for `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Cross-browser support for hyphenated text is not a reality yet with CSS only, but you can see a good roundup of what's possible here: 
http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/wiki/en_CSS3Hyphenation

Some browser-specific CSS is available for firefox and webkit browsers:

```
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: '~';
-moz-hyphens: auto;
```

The big issue with hyphenation is that it needs to be language aware to work properly, which is tricky.

Maybe a JS solution like this will help you?
http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/