# Text overflow ellipsis is not working in Windows(IE 10)

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, ellipsis

If DIV contains a long sentence, such as "if i had a dime for everytime i was told i can't", I want to display:

```
 |if i had a dime for|
 |everytime i was... |
```

By Using below code it working fine in IOS and android but it is not working in windows(IE 10), please help me on this.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td width="80%">
         <div style="width:100%;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;">
               if i had a dime for everytime i was told i can't                                                         
         </div>
     </td>
     <td width="20%">
          <img src=""/>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text

Answer (score 0):

Your desired effect is for a multi-line text block that cuts off with an ellipsis.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. `text-overflow:ellipsis` only works on a single-line. It requires you to specify `white-space:nowrap` (which you have done) and that forces the entire text onto a single line.

This is the standard and applies to all browsers, so I don't know how you're getting the desired effect on *any* browser. It certainly won't work in IE or any other current browser that I'm aware of.

There is an extension to `text-overflow` that allows an ellipsis on multi-line text, but it's only supported by Opera, so it's hardly worth mentioning. (but in case you are interested, the syntax is `text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline`).

There is a pure CSS solution [described here](https://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/), but it's a bit complex. It might be worth a try though.

The only other option you have is some sort of javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

**edit
correct myself; You need to have CSS overflow and width**

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/kaJ3L/1/

```
span {
border: solid 2px blue;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 100px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden
```

}

Comment: thanks, but i need it in second line, please check http://jsfiddle.net/kaJ3L/874/

Comment: @user2677473 - it can't be done in multi-line using standard CSS. `text-overflow:ellipsis` is explicitly designed for a single line.

Comment: ok, do we have solution using javascript? if so, can you share it