# Wordwrap Jquery X-Editable / Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I am using X-Editable javascript plug-in for bootstrap to make html tables editable. I have an issue when textareas are filled with lots of data it displays it in the table making it a messy page.

Are there any built in wordwrap features or line limits, I can't find anything in the APIs, what would be the best way to achieve this.

LINK TO FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/53kbfL4k/7/

```
 link to fiddle
```

Thanks

Comment: Adding some simple jsfiddle would help a lot.

Comment: good point, will create one now

Comment: added fiddle link, if you click on description or details and add lots of text you will see what I mean. When you have lots of rows it gets messy

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "messy"? Word-wrap works perfectly in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Well say I put 900 words in, it looks rubbish. I just want to cut it down to only display 1-2 lines of text per box on update.

Comment: Well, there are some discussions on this topic: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text). I don't think that it's supported by `x-editable` out of the box, so you'll have to play with CSS a little.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a play but I think its the javascript which needs editing to cut down the word length. Its a bit messy (x-editable)