# Max characters in a paragraph/sentence using css

Tags: html, css, text, character, limit

I have been using and trying to test the following css coding;

white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

...for this issue where text overflows but when using the above code it only works for the first line so I need help in trying to get the same outcome as the above coding but for a paragraph using CSS.

So instead of for example (which the current code does):
HP elitebook...

to

HP elitebook 17.3",
5 GB - 500GB -
Windows 8 ...

Please help, really appreciate your help!

Comment: CSS only? AFAIK you cannot (in any portable way, compatible with at least major browsers). With JavaScript there are many jQuery plugins for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text