# Paragraph overflow with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

So I have a cell with a fixed height with title and content(shown below).

When the screen size gets smaller, the title gets `text-overflow:ellipsis;`.

Here is the markup that I used for both title and content:

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

However with the content part (simple `div`), the content extends beyond the container (not shown in the picture). Also because content usually has a paragraph, when i apply the same css markup as above, it goes simply beyond the container in a long line without `break`.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the last part (red circle) in the image.

So, I already have outer cell `max-height`set. How can I make it so that the content stays within the cell `max-height` and whatever overflows goes to a next line and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is applied instead of a long straight line?

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you go jQuery, there is a nifty plugin called dotdotdot - https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.dotdotdot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use text-overflow:ellipsis on multiline text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text)

Comment: Vanilla JS lib https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js Useful info: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

Comment: Got it working by adding `overflow:hidden;` and what you provided. Thanks!

Comment: This works well, and incidentally enough, the `display` property is crucial.

Comment: Could you clarify why this works? For beginners that may not understand display: -webkit-box- and the other webkit rules.