# Make paragraph take the remaining height

Tags: html, css

Most questions and answers about taking remaining height are focused on the content section on the page. I've tried several answers to my scenario but couldn't solve it.

I have a vertical layout with four elements.

```
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 350px">
        <h1>Header Text 1</h1>
        <h2>Header Text 2</h2>
        <p>paragraph that should take the remaining space</p>          
        <a href="">Button</a>
    </div>
```

The height is fixed and will be enough to accommodate `h1`,`h2`,`a`. I want `p` element to take the remaining space and display as may lines of text as possible in that space. If space is not enough it should display dots `...` or some indicator.

I tried to set a fixed height for the paragraph but that doesn't work because I don't know how many lines `h1,h2` will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your problem is solvable with flex: https://jsbin.com/japojezofa/edit?html,css,output (sorry I'm on a phone.. In a jungle.. And stack overflow doesn't give me options to put code here)

However multi-line ellipses of a variable line length I think will be impossible with pure css (maybe you can fake it with a bottom-right aligned background image of "..."): [Is it possible to use text-overflow:ellipsis on multiline text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text)

**EDIT:** This is the code

```
.col-sm-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-sm-6 > * {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: heres an example of the webkit mentioned on your second link (unfortunately do not works on mozilla): [link](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp)

Comment: @Dominic Tobias Thanks! You nailed it. I'll add the working code to the answer, hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Dominic Tobias' answer, flexbox can do the height adjustment for you.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 350px">
  <h1>Header Text 1</h1>
  <h2>Header Text 2</h2>
  <p>paragraph that should take the remaining space</p>
  <a href="">Button</a>
</div>
```

As for the multi-line ellipsis he has provided one link...I will provide another.  - [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-ellipsis-to-multiline-text)

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code but it doesn't work when paragraph gets several lines. Take a look at [this demo](https://jsbin.com/yujehecubo/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: As mentioned in both answers you can't do the ellipsis with multi line text.

Comment: I meant the height adjustment not the ellipsis. As you can see in [this demo](https://jsbin.com/yujehecubo/edit?html,css,output) the paragraph's height is not constrained by the height of the `div`. Even the button is pushed outside the div

Comment: If the text is larger than the divs remaining space that's expected. You need to find an alternative method of dealing with the overflow. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZQqZoz

Comment: Using `overflow-y: auto` solves the overflow issue, well done. The question asks to hide the end of the paragraph if it doesn't fit but scrolling could be another approach. Thanks for your answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage(% like 95% or something) for height then whatever height h1 and h2 takes, percentage will assign the remaining height to p.

```
style="height:95%"
```

Comment: This is not a math problem!

Comment: Actually,u can use % for height. Try that out.

Comment: Actually he is not after the solution for a summation problem. He needs a dynamic CSS solution, in which he can end up with the height for `p`, regardless of any information about `h1`, ... heights

Comment: @pritesh I cannot use percent based height because I don't know the height of `h1`,`h2`. If I use something like 50% I might waste space when `h1` height is small or use to much space when it gets bigger. Thanks @Trix for explaining