# Text in Button (CSS)

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to customize my button, which has a long text on it.
When I **hover** on the button, I want that long text to *wrap* in 2 or 3 lines so that more text is visible on the button. Along with that, I want the rest of the text to be *ellipsed*.
somewhat like this:-

**original text:**

> This is a long text which (on hover) I want to wrap inside the button and show it in 3 lines, ending with ellipsis

**text in button (with fixed width of 250px):**

> This is a long text which (on hover)...

**text in button on hover (button height increases ):**

> This is a long text which (on hover)
>   I want to wrap inside the button and
>   show it in 3 lines, ending with e...

I have made a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RJHXtx?p=preview) in angularjs using `md-button` of angular-material.
Since I am not good at CSS, I am having trouble in customizing my button.

Answer (score 4):

```css
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button:hover {
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: none;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<button>
This is a long text which (on hover) I want to wrap inside the button and show it in 3 lines, ending with ellipsis  
</button>
```

Edit: I just realized you wanted to have the expanded version to have ellipsis, as well. I don't think it is possible to do that. See [this other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text) for more information on that.