# Trying to add ellipsis after the second line using sass/css?

Tags: html, css, sass

In the jsfiddle link you can find what I tried out, however when the text goes over two lines, I do not see the ellipsis anymore. Can somebody help me out. Im new to CSS, and what to solve this problem using CSS/SASS only.

```css
.exciting-text {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.exciting-text::after {
  content: "...";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="exciting-text">Contributing to MDN is easy and fun.Just hit the edit button to add new live samples, or improve existing samplesdfsfssfddcdxcxdsdzxfsfdsadasdaddsadsadsadsadsadasdasfds.</p>
```

Comment: `text-overflow` works **only for single lines**.

Comment: Sorry, I should have done it to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text but if you actually put a bit of effort in and googled this, you would have come across this code pen: http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: @pete, this example uses webkit, which I am trying to avoid at all cost, is there a way without using webkit and thanks for the link

Comment: not really - all the examples I have seen are either webkit, opera, js or server side truncation

Comment: how would you truncate text server-side in JS/nodeJS

Comment: js and node js is a client side language

Answer (score 0):

In current example your problem is `max-height`. Get rid of it and your pseudo ellipsis will be visible at all times.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, however i want to limit the text to two lines