# max number of text lines + ellipsis

Tags: css, text, overflow, line, whitespace

I have multiple titles with different lenghts and i would like them to always take 1 line and leave suspension points/ellipsis (...) if they can't fit. I can't just change the text inside the `div`s because the `h2`s inside them will automatically change everyday.

Heres my code: http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/k9LsLuuk/

You can see what I want to achieve at [Medium](http://medium.com) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Jc3.png

PS: If my english isn't good enough feel free to edit my question

EDIT: I got an asnswer that works perfectly for 1 line, but now I want the text to take 2 lines instead. Any ideas?

Comment: I have used this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ellipsize for this kind of situation. Check if it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since luckily you want *one* line,

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

should work for you. [MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9LsLuuk/1/)

Comment: @FranLegon: Then you're currently out of luck with pure CSS, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/7680712/505649 has some good pointers.