# limit number of characters in div using css

Tags: html, css

I have div with overflow:hidden and some text in it, last line is visible halfway. What should I do to hide this last line from div? Or even add some ellipsis.

Is is possible to do this with css only? (I don't want to change font size, or change display:hidden)

For example: (http://jsfiddle.net/xp32ekqc/)

html:

```
<div>
    Hello World, Hello World, Hello Booom
</div>
```

style:

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I'd like to see all text without "Boom" or instead of Hello Boom - Hel...

Comment: Change the font size? Change the box size? Change the overflow? Use js to calculate what's visible and strip the rest? There's many ways. Guess you need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you want something like an ellipsis with a "Read more" / "Read less" button?

Comment: Try like this http://jsfiddle.net/xp32ekqc/1/

Comment: @Pearson Doubt that's usable for OP since `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` is a fixed number and the content does not look static.

Comment: @Pearson Do you know how can I use it in other browsers?

Comment: @Marcin Doliwa you can manage it with **line-height** though

Comment: Yep you need to have an height that'd be a multiple of line height (see _vertical rythm_ also) like 60px = 20px x 3 lines. If font size was 15px then set `line-height: 1.333` (unitless) to have a line height of 20px

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css ellipsis on second line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line) and also [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458345/1355315)

Comment: take a look about text-overflow:ellipsis; other way using jquery

Comment: see i give one example in answer may be it will help you if you want any help let me know

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am facing same issue,if your text is in one line then **text overflow** working fine but now your doing something different i.e you want **...... after 4 or 5 line** so you have to apply ellipsis in height.

see this example:

```css
div {
    height:90px;
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.myDiv{
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp:5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    Hello World, Hello World, Hello Booom
</div>
```

As you can see in above example  -webkit-line-clamp:5; so it will add .... at 5 line.

**Note**: What is **-WebKit**

> WebKit is a HTML/CSS web browser rendering engine for Safari/Chrome.

**List of rendering engine for Web browser**

- **IE**

  - Engine: [Trident][2]
  - CSS-prefix: `-msie`
- **Firefox**

  - Engine: [Gecko][3]
  - CSS-prefix: `-moz`
- **Opera**

  - Engine: [Presto][4]
  - CSS-prefix: `-o`
- **Safari & Chrome**

  - Engine: [WebKit][5]
  - CSS-prefix: `-webkit`

> So for **Safari/Chrome**  use **-webkit** in **css** and for other
>   browser use **css-prefix** as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

In your css. I hope your helped with this. I have attached a link to jsfiddle: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/xp32ekqc/3/)

Comment: We, as a group here on Stack Overflow, would rather your answers focused on answering the question, and omitted such unnecessary fluff as "hello." Similarly, to improve your answer, it would be beneficial to format your code clearly as code. You should also take the time to describe how your answer works and what it does to solve the problem; that way the OP and others in future might learn something useful from this.