# How to fold a paragraph and replace the rest of the content with '...'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Well, I have content within a paragraph, maybe like this:

```
<div style="width:30px">
  <p>12345678901234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzIlovePaulinaVega</p>
</div>
```

We all know that the content will be divided into many rows because of its parent's width, but I just want to keep the top 2 rows, the rest is replaced with'...'. I am wondering how to accomplish it .Tell me please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/2zggrdur/

Comment: Here is the similar question, [css-ellipsis-on-second-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line)

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <p>12345678901234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzIlovePaulinaVega</p>
</div>
```

Add CSS like this:

```
p{
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I need to keep 2 rows.

Comment: Add a fixed height if that's allowed.

Comment: @Patrickgao91: what do you means by `rows` here?

Comment: Sorry...My English is quite poor...

Comment: Its just a paragraph text isn't it? or you are planning to do something else/

Comment: I want it on the second line

Comment: well, the problem for me is that the content within the paragraph may be made up with clutter letters and numbers(for example, 79ryeuriy832rwiueyr823rwiury32riwyr), I didn't find any answer work for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

### JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2zggrdur/1/

### CSS:

```
p {
        line-height: 1.5em;
        height: 3em;
           text-overflow:ellipsis; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

1. Specify height property to visible number lines or rows in your paragraph.
2. text-overflow:ellipsis and overflow:hidden will do hide and 3 dots properties.
3. Allighn parent width according to paragraph.

Comment: well, I replaced content within <p></p> with 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss...'(however, a lot of ss), It doesn't work... but thank you all the same. I think this problem should be solved with jquery