# Updating text-overflow property on resized element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to resize an element to be the same height as an adjacent element to keep a nice and clean flow in my web-page. I am using bootstrap's grid system.

Here is an example of the issue:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    var right = document.getElementById('right');

    right.style.height = left.clientHeight + "px";
    alert("Set height to: " + right.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
#left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#right {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.text {
  text-overflow: ellipses;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="left"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1x1/" width="50%"> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="right"> 
    <div class="text">
      a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text a lot of text 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the green border stops way before the text stops, and the `text-overflow` property is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapping element of the text.

```
#right {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

This causes the ellipsis to *kick in*.

In addition, you misspelled ellipsis (not ellipses):

```
.text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**EDIT**

It turns out it is impossible to add ellipsis not on the first line of text in css. CSS Tricks has some good workarounds https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Did you test this in a snippet? This does cut off the text, however does not apply the ellipsis.

Comment: It turns out there is no way to currently do this with css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line