# How to vertical align single or multiple line

Tags: html, css

How to vertical align single or multiple line ?

I need for ellipsis, because in some situations i want to show only one line, and sometimes two lines.

this is my code so far:

```
html, body, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.ellipsis {
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #AAA;
}

.blah {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.2em;
   line-height: 1.2em;
   display: block;

}
.blah:before {
    content:"";
    float: left;
    width: 5px;
    height: 3.6em;
}
.blah > *:first-child {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/0dqef9da/274/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css ellipsis on second line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line)

Comment: this is not my question... my question is How to vertical align single or multiple line

Comment: Your problem statement is ambiguous. "[...] in some situations i want to show only one line, and sometimes two lines". In what situations *exactly*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: for some titles i will use height: 1.2em;
   line-height: 1.2em;   and for some other titles will write: height: 2.4em;
   line-height: 1.2em;

Answer (score -2):

You should use `word-break:break-all`  in you text css style attribute

Answer (score -2):

Vertical align center you use simply `text-align: center;` and if you want to use ellipsis

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

please follow the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

In ellipsis you need also div width.. Please check the above code

Comment: how to display two lines ? if i need

Comment: You (incorrectly) state that `text-align: center` will vertically align, and then omit it completely from your solution...

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line