# fix table header to two lines with three dots

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, bootstrap-4

There is a table with `thead` and i need to fix to two lines the elements in inside it to, I mean if this header text is longer than two lines, remaining part of text must be shown with three dots. Hovewer instead of two line break, i can only make `white-space:nowrap` with one line and 
[image: it is shown like that:]

How can i achieve that?

UPDATE:
When i add `.table thead th {
    display: -webkit-box!important;

   -webkit-line-clamp: 2!important;

   -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;

   overflow: hidden!important; 
}` , it shows the column of table as vertical like that: [image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line

Comment: @Sim I update the question after your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code i suggest:

```
.content{   
   display: -webkit-box;   
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;   
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;     
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

more info here: https://medium.com/@elad/trimming-multi-lines-in-css-5ae59d5e6d84

Answer (score 0):

Use this css properties

```
.class {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```