# Trim string for given space while word break multiline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

I have a sidebar where I want to give the heading and the description a max of two lines. However, the height of the span should always be two rows long in order to have the same vertical alignment. Also, I don't want the the last word to break, it should just replace the it with `...`. For example if the last word wouldn't fit in the given space, it shouldn't just break the word into the next row, instead it should look like this `this is my descirpti...`.

The word should just be cutted and be appended by `...`.

Also, is it possible to add a class to every `div` where the text got cutted? I want to have a special style for those cases!

I want to solve this with the CSS property `text-overflow`

```css
.max-width-200 {
  max-width: 900px;
}

span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.heading-wrapper ,.description-wrapper {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row max-width-200">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/180">   
      </div>
      <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-wrap">
         <div class="col-12 no-padding align-self-start heading-wrapper">
            <span>This is my heading, its not very long</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 no-padding align-self-center description-wrapper">
            <span>This is my description. This description is longer then it should be. It should only be two rows large but unfortuntly its longer then two rows.</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="row max-width-200">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/180">   
      </div>
      <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-wrap">
         <div class="col-12 no-padding align-self-start heading-wrapper">
            <span>This is my heading, Its longer then it should be.. someone fucked it up. Please fix me to be only two rows long!</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 no-padding align-self-center description-wrapper">
            <span>This is my description. This description is longer then it should be. It should only be two rows large but unfortuntly its longer then two rows.</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
  span {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  }
```

Usually `text-overflow: ellipsis;` needs a `white-space` attribute to be set, in order to work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680712/8177490

You should also check for browser compatibility before using it.

If you don't want the heading to be affected change its tag from `span` to `p` or some `h` tag.