# Webpack is removing css rules

Tags: css, webpack, stylelint

I have this block of CSS code:

```
.accordeon:not(.accordeon--expanded) .accordeon__intro {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  height: 2.7em;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

That using the `yarn dev` webpacks removes the last line.

I fixed it by adding `/* stylelint-disable */`

```
.accordeon:not(.accordeon--expanded) .accordeon__intro {
  /* stylelint-disable */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  height: 2.7em;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* stylelint-enable */
}
```

But when I run `yarn build` the issue returns.

This is the info of package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=prod webpack -p",
    "build:staging": "NODE_ENV=staging webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "j@tmpo.io",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-webpack-loaders": "^0.9.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "gsap": "^3.0.5",
    "lax.js": "^1.2.5",
    "pixi.js": "^5.2.0",
    "preact": "^7.2.0",
    "preact-compat": "^3.19.0",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^3.7.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "react-before-after-slider": "^1.0.4",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.7",
    "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap": "^1.0.4",
    "unfetch": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Any idea how to prevent this? it does even remove if I put it inline `style="-webkit-box-orient: vertical;"` resulting in a empty `style`

-edit-

This is what i find related in the webpack.config.js but [this](https://pastebin.com/Z7yMjJvU) is the full code

```
module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: { presets: ["es2015", "stage-0"] },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
            loader: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"],
          }),
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ttf|svg|eot|woff|woff2)$/i,
          loader: "file-loader?name=/assets/[path][name].[ext]&publicPath=.",
        },
        { test: /icon_.+\.(svg)$/i, loader: "url-loader" },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
      ],
    },
```

My postcss.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 3 version'] })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your webpack config? Seems that it is related to stylelint somehow

Comment: @felixmosh I edited with that info, thanks

Comment: Your webpack config looks simple & OK, can you add your postcss config?

Comment: @felixmosh added, thanks!

Comment: Probably your autoprefixer is removing deprecated css declarations, in prod mod, all comments are stripped therefore your comment rule not helps. try to remove autoprefixer, just to prove the point

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your question, but I think you should reconsider using box-orient. box-orient is a deprecated feature and has been replaced by the new flexbox standard. You might get it in somehow, but stylelint has good reasons to remove it.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

> This is a property of the original CSS Flexible Box Layout Module draft, and has been replaced by a newer standard. See flexbox for information about the current standard.

Comment: You are very right, but I don't know how else to achieve this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049457/533941 Any thoughts? thanks!