# Is there a way to put the paragraph on multiple lines in limited space?

Tags: html, css, django

i have this project:

User should be able to add a comment in a box but the box is have max lenght of 250 characters.

This is my snippet from Html:

```
<div class="comment-box">
    
    <div class="list-comments">
        <span> Comments </span>
        <hr>
        {%for i in comments.all%}
            <div class="comment">
                <p class="description">
                    {{i.description}} 
                </p>
                <p>
                    <i><b>{{i.user}}</b>, {{i.date}}</i>
                </p>
            </div>
        {%empty%}
            <p> There aren't comment here! </p>
        {%endfor%} 
    </div>
    
    <div class="leave-comment">
        <form action="{% url 'add_comment' item.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{comment_form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Send comment" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Mine css

```
.comment-box{
margin: auto;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 60%;
border: 1px groove rgb(133, 133, 219);
border-radius: 5px;

}

 .list-comments{
    padding: 5px;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
}

.leave-comment{
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex-basis: 30%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.comment{
    border: 1px groove rgb(133, 133, 219);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
    
.description{
    max-width: 320ch;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In this case i added like 250 "1" to see the result.
And this is the result

[image]

The problem is that the comment is displayed with ... and not entire comment.

**Is there a way to put the comment on multiple lines in limited space?**

EDIT: ACTUAL SOLUTION

Css

```
textarea{
    width:430px;
    height: 130px;
    resize: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea readonly>
     {{i.description}} 
</textarea>
<p>
   <i><b>{{i.user}}</b>, {{i.date}}</i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

well actually CSS has no standard method for doing  text-overflow: ellipsis; on multiline texts
this question was quite similar to yours:
[css ellipsis on second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269713/css-ellipsis-on-second-line)

Comment: I think about a Textarea readonly.. it isnt really good to see but better than other

Comment: Otherwise how is it possible? Javascript? or something else?

Comment: well since we can`t  handle this ellipsis problem with CSS standard methods it`s actually a great solution

Comment: you can handle it with JS, but that textarea solution that you just said is quite enough and it can do what you want