# Add dots to truncate multiline overflow CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to add 3 dots '...' to truncate long text multinine. We can Not use

```
-webkit-line-clamp: X;
```

Since we do not know the number of rows or owr text. The phader item has fixed height and the text can be changed, so, its long will be different. I have tested several ways, the most ideal is this one:

```
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
max-height: 96%
```

It works but I need to add 3 dots at the end of truncate text.

Any help? thank you in advance

Comment: text-overflow: ellipsis; only works for 1 line text.

Comment: @user14275998 Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678040/how-to-add-an-ellipsis-on-the-third-line-of-text/71678263#71678263

Comment: I con not use -webkit-line-clamp: 3; Because it is variable, depending on another <p> element size, so some times it is 3 another 4 , ...

Comment: Then you are out of luck my friend