# text-overflow: ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css

This is what I tried (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaJ3L/)):

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    border: solid 2px blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Essentially, I want the span to shrink with ellipsis when the window is made small. What did I do wrong?

Comment: the requirements for ellipsis to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Comment: The problem I had when I thought it wasn't working was I didn't set the width long enough (10px). So I was cutting off the ellipsis, doh!

Comment: CSS display is block

Comment: You need `display: block` with `width: 100%;` or `display: inline-block.` Ellipsis cannot be calculated in `display:inline` element (span's default.) See this [text overflow not working tutorial](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) for implementation.

Comment: Make sure to explicitly specify width[.](https://semicolon.dev/stackoverflow/question/9/how-to-fix-css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working-in-a-span-element)

Answer (score 574, accepted):

You need to have CSS `overflow`, `width` (or `max-width`), `display`, and `white-space`.

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/kaJ3L/1/

```css
span {
    border: solid 2px blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    border: solid 2px blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<span>Test test test test test test</span>
```

---

**Addendum**
If you want an overview of techniques to do line clamping (Multiline Overflow Ellipses), look at this CSS-Tricks page: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

**Addendum2** (May 2019)
As this [link](https://www.bram.us/2019/05/21/truncating-multi-line-text-with-css/70687/) claims, Firefox 68 will support `-webkit-line-clamp` (!)

Comment: The white-space property was what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: It sucks that you need the `white-space: nowrap;` property. Now you only can make one line of text end with ... instead of a block text.

Comment: For Firefox, we also need to specify a `height` property, e.g.: `height:10px`.

Comment: This answer was posted over 2 years ago, when the browser support was much worse than it is today.

Comment: Today, all the major browsers support ellipsis:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow

Comment: I am using % for width in my DIV but I don't see the ellipses :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342411/how-to-display-an-image-next-to-some-texts

Comment: It's worth noting that you also need the `overflow: hidden` as mentioned by @ZippyV in his answer.

Comment: How would the solution look like with multiple lines, e.g. by saying width:250px and height:200px?

Comment: @basZero Multiline Ellipsis is not supported with CSS alone. You have to take other measures

Comment: If you want to cut the text in a large block, you are better off cutting it down in the back-end with string manipulation to cut the text down and add the dots at the end.

Comment: Yeah, but presentation sucks. As the number of characters of two different texts may be the same, but the text-width may differ. You cannot solve this on the server, as it depends on OS, browser and screen/window size

Comment: you also have to make sure your font supports ellipsis

Comment: @quem you can of course just add a custom string `text-overflow: " ..."`

Comment: You need to specify a width so the container is bound, you need to set overflow:hidden so the browser will hide the run-over text, and then set text-overflow:ellipsis to instruct the browser how to especially handle text overflow hiding.

Comment: Yes, 256th upvote. There is a certain rewarding feeling about having a power-of-2 amount of upvotes...

Comment: @Hoffmann Why? Do you have an example, where it is not working?

Comment: @HerrSerker For some reason it only works with display block elements. Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaoxJv

Comment: @Hoffmann Wrap the content in your flex in a div and add ellipsis style to that: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/MqYdWy

Comment: on chrome 68, i could achieve it whitout white-space

Comment: @HerrSerker sure that works, but if your element has say flex:1 to be able to fit its display:flex parent then wrapping it would break that

Comment: @Hoffmann I updated my pen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/MqYdWy Check it again!

Comment: For those using bootstrap 4, this can be accomplished by adding these classes to the span element: "d-block text-nowrap text-truncate w-100"

Comment: if you have a dynamic width parent container, you can set min-width: auto to adjust to content. Then you will have ellipses when you shrink smaller than the word.

Answer (score 52):

Make sure you have a block element, a maximum size and set overflow to hidden. (Tested in IE9 and FF 7)

http://jsfiddle.net/uh9zD/

```
div {
    border: solid 2px blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Seems like that white-space:nowrap property may be generally necessary as well, for anything with spaces.

Comment: There is quirk in IE -- [IE doesn't wrap a second word](http://jsfiddle.net/vgLwbxsx/1/)  (tested in IE 11)... Go figure. Works in any other browser as expected (including good old Opera 12).

Comment: @Nux This is also not working as expected in MS Edge browser

Answer (score 31):

For multi-lines in Chrome use :

```
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2; // max nb lines to show
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Inspired from youtube ;-)

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. It uses `-webkit-*` properties, but is supported in all major browsers. More info can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 13):

### For multiple lines

In chrome, you can apply this css if you need to apply ellipsis on multiple lines.

You can also add *width* in your css to specify element of certain width:

```css
.multi-line-ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p class="multi-line-ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

this and only this did the job for me 
for a

```
<pre> </pre>
```

tag

everthing else failed to do the ellipsis....

Answer (score 7):

Just a headsup for anyone who may stumble across this... My h2 was inheriting

```
text-rendering: optimizelegibility; 
//Changed to text-rendering: none; for fix
```

which was not allowing ellipsis. Apparently this is very finickey eh?

Answer (score 6):

I was having an issue with ellipsis under chrome. Turning on white-space: nowrap seemed to fix it.

```
max-width: 95px;
max-height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
border: solid 1px black;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: right;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 5):

### Without Fixed Width

For those of us that **do not** want to use fixed-width, it also works using `display: inline-grid`. So along with required properties, you just add `display`

```
span {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-grid;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-grid` gave some undesired results for me, `display: inline` worked though!

Answer (score 3):

Add this below code for where you likes to

example

```
p{
   display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
   display: -webkit-box;
   max-width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using ellipsis by adding the following in CSS:

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But it seems like this code just applies to one-line trim. More ways to trim text and show ellipsis can be found in this website: http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=631

Answer (score 1):

This code would work great and also thanks to the `title` HTML prop the full text will be shown on-hover by default

```css
.truncated {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  /* Optional: set a fixed max-width or width to the element if needed */
  max-width: 200px; /* max-width: 100%; also works */
}
```

```html
<div class="truncated" title="This is a long text that will be truncated, but showed on hover">
  This is a long text that will be truncated, but shown on hover
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following lines in CSS for ellipsis to work

```
 p {
     display: block; // change it as per your requirement
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

- `overflow-x: clip` to just collapse it horizontally
- `white-space: nowrap` to avoid a new line
- `text-overflow: ellipsis` to add the `...` at the end

```
overflow-x: clip;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Have into account that display as `flex` it wont work, just change it to one that suites your needs.