# how to apply ellipse effect in <span> which contain space in string?

Tags: html, css

i want to show ellipsis after some width.i want to do this with css. & only in one span tag.(no other tag should used label..etc). how can i achieve this.

`<span>Name: Patrick Jonson</span>`

output should be below one

```
Name: Patrick jon...
```

problem is that it break word when space appear.

Please help.

Comment: You should search for an answer before asking a question like this

Comment: `"i already used below css"`... What is this "below css"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [text-overflow: ellipsis not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly...this is straightforward enough to accomplish-

## **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/88u3R/)**

HTML

```
<span class='ellipsis'>Name: Patrick Jonson</span>
```

CSS

```
span.ellipsis{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:130px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this cant be accomplished with CSS alone unfortunately.

Comment: This only works if the content is static. In which case, boom indeed!