# Text-ellipsis property for Option tag not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Text-overflow: ellipsis property is working for DIV tag but not for OPTION tag in IE. Tags like DIV and SPAN (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)) are working fine, but OPTION tag doesn't work good.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .div-style
    {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        word-wrap: normal;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .option-style
    {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        word-wrap: normal;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div-style">
        This is a sample div to check text-oveflow property in IE.
    </div>
    <div>
        <select size="6">
            <option class="option-style">This is a very long option 1</option>
            <option class="option-style">Option 2</option>
            <option class="option-style">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The same works well in Firefox. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nicael that link doesnt help :( This is about the option tag

Comment: You are very limited in what you can style in most form controls, even moreso in IE. See the duplicate I marked form more information. For reference the `text-ellipsis` setting on the `option` is not working form me in Chrome on OSX.