# Firefox Issue: Textoverflow in inputbox

Tags: css, firefox, input, textbox

This is a weird issue in Firefox.

Enter a text greater than the width of the input box.

**Expected**

Input element will reset to the beginning and ellipsis will be shown

**What actually happens**

Input element stays at the scrolled position and ellipsis does not appear.

If you go to the beginning of the input box, there is a possibility (not sure why) that the ellipsis will be visible when you deselect the box.

Firefox -> [image: Image1], [image: Image2]

Chrome -> [image]

Edge -> [image: Image1], [image: Image2]

```css
input {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: This might help --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/7993098/5561605

Comment: For other elements, the link you shared (and the one that I have done) works. But for input element, the issue still persists.