# Long text should be hidden by css

Tags: css, text, overflow

I have code like this.
html:

```
<div>
    <h3>Sometext</h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 20px;   
}
h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Problem here is that H3 tag "Sometext" should only written as "Somete" but both overflow and text-overflow doesn't help. H3 tag still can be seen.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want.. You want it to display "Somete" but you don't what it to be seen.. Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: I mean that I have div and h3 in this div. If the text can't fit in special width of div I want to make last 3 words of this text (which can fit in) be hidden and replaced with ". . ."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow: ellipsis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use text-overflow:clip; and width to h3

```css
h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    width: 59px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Sometext</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: then you use text-overflow: ellipsis; but it will display somet... using width 72px

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```css
h3 {   
    width: 70px;  
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Sometext</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-overflow: ellipsis is also working fine for me but u decleare width 20px is so less to show a text with three ellipsis dot (...). that's why it's only showing simple ...

just increase width like 70px and it will work..and when u mention overflow hidden then u don't need to specify `text-overflow: clip`.

```
width: 70px; text-overflow: clip
```