# How to hide the overflow content in material ui table cell instead of wrapping

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the material UI Table component to render a table. I want to show `...` ellipsis when the content in a cell over flows. The current behavior is that it wraps text inside the cell. I tried adding CSS styles but it does not work. How do I achieve this?

```
import React from "react";
// import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData(
    "Ice cream sandwich dsdadsads dsadsadsadsa dsadasdsadsa dsadsadsa dsadsads asdsadsadsadsa",
    237,
    9.0,
    37,
    4.3
  ),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

export default function SimpleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell style={{root:{overflowX: 'hidden', textOverflow: "ellipsis"}}} className="overflow-test" component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

```
.overflow-test {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
```

[image: Edit modern-resonance-hme4s]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React from "react";
// import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import Css from "./styles.css";

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData(
    "Ice cream sandwich dsdadsads dsadsadsadsa dsadasdsadsa dsadsadsa dsadsads asdsadsadsadsa",
    237,
    9.0,
    37,
    4.3
  ),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

export default function SimpleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                <div className={Css.textContainer}>
                 {row.name}
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

```css
.textContainer {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You need to specify a width to a container and then apply ellisis style to it.

Comment: I updated the sandbox to include your code. But it's not working. Please take a look at the sandbox

Comment: @Sruthi I'm unable to view your sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-water-fmn0b - can you go to this link

Comment: @Sruthi. An error occured when fetching the sandbox:

Comment: How can I do this without giving a fixed width to cell? Can I do it with %width?

Comment: @Sruthi %width will not work, instead use `width: calc(100vh - Xpx);`

Answer (score 6):

Two notice points

- You don't need `root` inside `inline-styles`, remove it
- CSS for `...`

```
  style={{
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    width: "300px",
    display: "block",
    overflow: "hidden"
  }}
```

[image]

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit optimistic-hodgkin-txitt]

---

Related QA: [text-overflow: ellipsis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Comment: Directly applying CSS on `TableCell` as `display: block` might disturb the `TableCell` Css.

Comment: @Shiladitya Yeah you are right. I just picked a minimum diff from the demo to explain what's needed.

Answer (score 5):

To keep the overflowing cell responsive, add `table-layout: fixed;` to the Table component. If needed TableCell can be given `width: auto` or a fixed width.