# Wrap a text within only two lines inside div

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap a text within only two lines inside div of specific width. If text goes beyond the length of two lines then I want to show ellipses.
Is there a way to do that using CSS?

e.g.

```
Sample text showing wrapping
of text in only two line...
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Limiting output to two lines of text is possible with CSS, if you set the `line-height` and `height` of the element, and set `overflow:hidden;`:

```
#someDiv {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;       /* height is 2x line-height, so two lines will display */
    overflow: hidden;  /* prevents extra lines from being visible */
}
```

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/sxk8n/)

Alternatively, you can use the CSS `text-overflow` and `white-space` properties to add ellipses, but this only appears to work for a single line.

```
#someDiv {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And a demo:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/sxk8n/1/)

Achieving both multiple lines of text and ellipses appears to be the realm of javascript.

Comment: I only see one line going across for some reason :/

Comment: The second example has only one line, when the requested solution requires two.

Comment: The third example does not work for me, tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: In that broken example `white-space: nowrap;` breaks it, if you comment it out it works.

Comment: Did someone change something in 2022? I used to do this and worked like a charm, but it seems it doesn't work anymore in my browser. I tested it in Chrome and Firefox, but ellipses are not shown. Even in the jsFiddle. See other answer by @vinesh https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585024/5830500 this works.

Answer (score 110):

Another simple and quick solution

```
.giveMeEllipsis {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: N; /* number of lines to show */
   line-height: X;        /* fallback */
   max-height: X*N;       /* fallback */
}
```

The reference to the original question and answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924997/842386)

Comment: Amazing solution!  I haven't fully tested it, but at first try, this works very well

Comment: @vinesh this solution is on fire! 

Comment: Seems `box-orient` is [deprecated or obsolete](https://caniuse.com/#search=box-orient).

Comment: Works! Tested this inside a `mat-card-content` in a `flexbox container`

Comment: For Firefox (and firefox Android) `box-orient` Can be enabled by setting `layout.css.prefixes.webkit = true` and changing the CSS to `-moz-webkit-box`

Answer (score 32):

**CSS only**

```
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Comment: This, requires box-orient property set to vertical but `box-orient` is non-standart.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others.

Answer (score 22):

The best one I've seen which is CSS only and responsive comes from [Mobify Developer Blog - CSS Ellipsis: How to Manage Multi-Line Ellipsis in Pure CSS](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/):

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0dqef9da/)

CSS:

```
html, body, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif;}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #AAA; }

.ellipsis:before {
    content:"";
    float: left;
    width: 5px; height: 200px; }

.ellipsis > *:first-child {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px; }        

.ellipsis:after {
    content: "\02026";  

    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    float: right; position: relative;
    top: -25px; left: 100%; 
    width: 3em; margin-left: -3em;
    padding-right: 5px;

    text-align: right;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
        from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(white), color-stop(50%, white));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);           
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%, white); }
```

Html:

```
<div class="ellipsis">
    <div class="blah">
        <p>Call me Ishmael. Some years ago &ndash; never mind how long precisely &ndash; having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen, and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off &ndash; then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best solution I've seen so far. 
You might want to reduce the height (200px) variable in the fiddle, for my screen size the text did not overflow initially.

Answer (score 16):

I believe the CSS-only solution `text-overflow: ellipsis` applies to one line only, so you won't be able to go this route:

```
.yourdiv {

    line-height: 1.5em; /* Sets line height to 1.5 times text size */
    height: 3em; /* Sets the div height to 2x line-height (3 times text size) */
    width: 100%; /* Use whatever width you want */
    white-space: normal; /* Wrap lines of text */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide text that goes beyond the boundaries of the div */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Ellipses (cross-browser) */
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Ellipses (cross-browser) */
}
```

Have you tried http://tpgblog.com/threedots/ for jQuery?

Comment: as I mentioned, combining ellipses with multiple lines of text doesn't appear to work, at least not for me in Chrome.

Comment: This worked in my current problem after I added: `display: block` and `min-height:  13px` and `max-height:  26px` for setting height for a `<td>`

Answer (score 16):

CSS only solution for Webkit

```js
// Only for DEMO
$(function() {

  $('#toggleWidth').on('click', function(e) {

    $('.multiLineLabel').toggleClass('maxWidth');

  });

})
```

```css
.multiLineLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.multiLineLabel .textMaxLine {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Only for DEMO */

.multiLineLabel.maxWidth {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiLineLabel">
  <span class="textMaxLine">This text is going to wrap automatically in 2 lines in case the width of the element is not sufficiently wide.</span>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="toggleWidth">Toggle Width</button>
```

Comment: This the best solution and must be marked as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was really looking for this one!

Comment: `-webkit-box-orient`
_This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used._ https://caniuse.com/?search=box-orient

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6jdj3pcL/1/

```
<p>Here is a paragraph with a lot of text ...</p>

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}

p::before {
   content: '...';
   float: right;
   margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: I don't find this solution ideal because it adds ellipsis even if the text doesn't overflow or even if the text fits in one line.

Answer (score 5):

Typically a one-line truncate is quite simple

```
.truncate-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Two line truncate is a little bit more tricky, but it can be done with css this example is in sass.

```
@mixin multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2rem, $lineCount: 2, $bgColor: white, $padding-right: 0.3125rem, $width: 1rem, $ellipsis-right: 0) {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide text if it is more than $lineCount lines  */
  position: relative; /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  line-height: $lineHeight; /* use this value to count block height */
  max-height: $lineHeight * $lineCount; /* max-height = line-height * lines max number */
  padding-right: $padding-right; /* place for '...' */
  white-space: normal; /* overwrite any white-space styles */
  word-break: break-all; /* will break each letter in word */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* show ellipsis if text is broken */

  &::before {
    content: '...'; /* create the '...'' points in the end */
    position: absolute;
    right: $ellipsis-right;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  &::after {
    content: ''; /* hide '...'' if we have text, which is less than or equal to max lines and add $bgColor */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: $width;
    height: 1rem * $lineCount;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
    background: $bgColor; /* because we are cutting off the diff we need to add the color back. */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/SWcCt/.

Just set a `line-height` the half of `height`:

```
line-height:20px;
height:40px;
```

Of course, in order to make `text-overflow: ellipsis` work you also need:

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space: pre;
```

Comment: This solution isnt flexible and requires a manual line break in the source text. Note that http://jsfiddle.net/SWcCt/282/ each box only contains one line of text. The desired solution would look like the 2nd box of http://jsfiddle.net/SWcCt/283/ except with an ellipsis at the end of the 2nd line.

Comment: @JoshuaCoady Good point, but `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works for inline boxes which overflow the line box. Without `white-space: pre` they would just go to the next line box. And then a manual line break is needed. I don't think there is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<tag> {
  max-height: calc(2 * 1.5em); /* 2 lines of 1.5em each */
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

This code uses the **-webkit-box** and **-webkit-line-clamp** properties to achieve the desired effect of showing only 2 lines of text and then adding ellipses for any remaining text. The **max-height** property sets the maximum height of the p element to 3em (2 lines of 1.5em each), and line-height sets the height of each line to 1.5em. The overflow property is set to hidden to hide any overflow beyond the maximum height, and **text-overflow** is set to ellipsis to add ellipses for any hidden text.

Answer (score 1):

@Asiddeen bn Muhammad's solution worked for me with a little modification to the css

```
    .text {
 line-height: 1.5;
  height: 6em; 
white-space: normal;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: block;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me:

CSS:

```
.longWordBreakParent {
  display: flex;
}
.longWordBreak {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="longWordBreakParent">
    <span className='longWordBreak'>someverylongtextthatcannotbefitinoneline</span>
</div>
```

For more details, see:
. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others.

Comment: Just like others, got that answer after a lot of trials in Chrome console. For more details, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break .

Comment: I meant as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for this "Achieving both multiple lines of text and ellipses appears to be the realm of Javascript".

WebkitLineClamp: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp
WebKItBoxOrient:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient

```
`.textWithTwoLine {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  }`
```

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others.

Answer (score -3):

In all these examples, let’s assume we have:

```
#someDiv {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: How this make sure that only 2 lines are shown? It only deals with the width of the div.

Comment: Please explain your code as it will make it more helpful for others. Please also use a comment for this type of message.