# Material-ui: write text in exactly 2 lines with ellipsis

Tags: reactjs, text, material-ui

For a reactjs app, I use Material-ui (https://material-ui.com/) for the design. And I need to write text in card that match exactly 2 lines.

What I've already done works when text can be contained in 2 or 1 lines, but for longer text, the cut becomes before word and it is not ellipsis.

[image]

Here what I've done

```
   <Box
        fontSize="h5.fontSize"
        component="div"
        overflow="hidden"
        textOverflow="ellipsis"
        height={70}
      >
        {title}
      </Box>
```

The result is good on the first card, for on the second one, the last word 'Floooooo' is displayed in the hidden part (the third line) but not in the second line with ellipsis. I've tried to add whiteSpace="nowrap" but the text is only 1 line height (fig 2) [image]

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 26):

```js
<Typography
  sx={{
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    display: "-webkit-box",
    WebkitLineClamp: "2",
    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
  }}>
  overflowing text...
</Typography>
```

#### Note

> 'sx' is a property that works in newer version of MUI

Comment: FYI works in all browsers except IE and Opera Mini

Answer (score 7):

You can use CSS rule `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` in conjuction with `word-break: break-all`

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  media: {
    height: 100,
  },
  customBox: {
    display: "-webkit-box",
    boxOrient: "vertical",
    lineClamp: 2,
    wordBreak: "break-all",
    overflow: "hidden"
  }
});

function App() {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const title = "pos2 test long Flooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo";

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Box
          fontSize="h5.fontSize"
          component="div"
          classes={{root: classes.customBox}}
        >
          {title}
        </Box>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { Box, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, makeStyles } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's quite good, I was impired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989546/wrap-a-text-within-only-two-lines-inside-div for finding my solution. The problem with yours is that all words are cut. In my case, I can have the word "long" cut in  lines

Comment: It's working!!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<CardContent style={{width: "auto"}}>
          <Box
            fontSize="h5.fontSize"
            component="div" 
            overflow="hidden"            
            whiteSpace="pre-line"
            textOverflow="ellipsis"
            height={70}          
          >
            {title}
          </Box>
</CardContent>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, no change, still as the first image

Comment: Hope there is a width set for outer element of Box!

Comment: it's just a CardContent, without any specification

Comment: Try setting width: "auto" to CardContent or use two box with setting width: auto for outer Box and giving above style to inner Box.

Comment: thank for your help, but again no change. I'm not sure a solution exists for my need

Answer (score 1):

For those who wants to override `noWrap` property on `Typography` component, you can do this in your `createTheme()` as follows:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiTypography: {
            styleOverrides: {
                noWrap: {
                    whiteSpace: "initial",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                    display: "-webkit-box",
                    WebkitLineClamp: "2",
                    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    [...] //your other overrides
});
```

Then just use in your code as usually:

`<Typography noWrap>[Your overflowing text]</Typography>`

More info about this here:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#overrides-based-on-props

---

If you want the number of lines to be customizable I came to this pretty ugly solution:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiTypography: {
            styleOverrides: {
                noWrap(styles) {
                    return {
                        whiteSpace: "initial",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                        display: "-webkit-box",
                        WebkitLineClamp: String(styles.ownerState['data-lines'] || '2'),
                        WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    [...] //your other overrides
});
```

Then:

`<Typography noWrap data-lines="3">[Your overflowing text]</Typography>`