# Multiline ellipsis for HTML (not text) with GWT

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I am getting an `HTML` string from from a *REST* server, it looks something like that:

```
"... text with a <span class='myClass'>stylized phrase</span> and then some ..."
```

I need to inject it to a `GWT HTMLPanel` as an `HTML` (i.e `element.setInnerHtml(str)`).

The only `HTML tags` in the string are these kind of spans (I don't know how many).
My problem is when doing this in `GWT` I have to account for those `span HTML tags` and it makes it much more complex.

I have tried `CSS` ellipsis effect:

```
.myElement {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But it works only for one-liners, and I'd like for it to be 2 lines before the ellipsis (in order to fill more of the containing *div*).

The only resort I have now is doing [this trick](http://www.mobify.com/dev/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css), which seems to me like an overkill.
I would prefer doing this in `GWT`, does anyone have an idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to try out

1) Inject `<BR/>` tags

2) Use additional cssproperty like  `-webkit-line-clamp: N; /* number of lines to show */`
 [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Neither approach is completely clean.

Comment: Have tried this, http://codepen.io/joe/pen/hfybL , but this only works on `webkit` based browsers (like `Chrome` and `Safari`) but not on my `Firefox` `IE9` and `Opera`.

Comment: Yes as the css property prefix mentions its webkit only. Workarounds need to be found for other browsers - http://www.css-101.org/articles/line-clamp/line-clamp_for_non_webkit-based_browsers.php