# Restricting text in two lines using css only

Tags: html, css

I want to limit the text to two lines inside a `<div>`

If the text is coming in more than two lines, then it should hide rest of the text after displaying two lines

For example:

> Long text continues
>
> down the road
>
> into a lane.

*****this should come as:

> Long text continues
>
> down the road

I have to do it using css only..

Please suggest?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about fixing the height of your div to be exactly two lines high, and using `overflow:hidden;`?

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .twolines
  {
     font-size: 20px;
     height: 48px;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

You could also use `em` values and `line-height`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .twolines
  {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 1em;
     height: 2em;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Here's a complete, working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
     .twolines
     {
        font-size: 1em;
        background-color: silver;
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 2em;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
     .twolines p
     {
        margin: 0;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="twolines">
     <p>Long text continues</p>
     <p>down the road</p>
     <p>into a lane.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried it by setting the div height and overflow:hidden but still it appears in three lines

Comment: Then increase the `line-height:25px`. This may solve your problem.

Comment: user, make a JSFiddle or something and replicate your issue please so we can help you figure out what isn't working properly.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues to the answer stated above - @user2385986

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfjgu/).

The HTML:

```
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div{background:gray; width:100px; height:40px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Hope this Helps.