# Cheating text-overflow + -webkit-line-clamp?

Tags: html, ellipsis, css

Here is an example copied from this question

[Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

The solution as shown in the fiddle looks good until I change the line-height to something like 60%. Then the following text show up after the ellipsis. Notice the text after '...' in the image below.

[image]

My change to line-height in the CSS is below.

```
.box .text {
    color:                      #333;
    padding:                    20px;
    width:                      204px;
    overflow:                   hidden;
    background:                 #E0E0E0;
    font-size:                  .95em;
    line-height:                1;
    text-align:                 justify;
    line-height: 60%; /* Added line height here */
}
```

My fiddle is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/marsant/csYjC/1140/

Is there away to avoid this cheating-like appearance? So text will not appear after the ellipsis regardless of line-height change.

Comment: Yes, there is a way: wait for `max-lines` to become widely supported! Hacks like these break when you change stuff and you need to make a compensating change in your CSS too. The numbers used in that post were carefully crafted.

Comment: There isn't a solution for this.  The height you use *must* depend on the font-size and the line-height.  You can't change the line-height without also changing the height of the container.  You might find this demo useful, though:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/nrBeg