# Pure CSS Ellipsis For Three or More Lines of Text

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

Is there a CSS-only way (no JavaScript/jQuery) to only show the first two lines and, if there are three or more lines, hide the extra lines and show an ellipsis?

For example, how can I take this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0yyr3e63/

...and make it look like this?

```
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
Sit Amet Consectetur

Ut Enim Ad Minim
Veniam Quis Nostrud...

Duis Aute Irure
Dolor In...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Comment: @Paulie_D I read that post but it doesn't have an actual useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  `text-overflow:ellipsis` property with `height`.

Like this

```
.truncate 
{
width: 250px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
height:100px;
}
```

By using text-overflow, you can display your output without using javascript.

Sources

[Source Link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

[To Learn more about truncating. Read this link](http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/)

**New Update**

For multiline ellipsis you can use this method.

```
css
.classname:after{
content: "\02026";
}
```

[Multiline-Ellipsis](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

Few Links which i think might be useful

[1.Codepen example](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp)

[2.Css Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)

Comment: I think the OP is aware of `text-overflow: ellipsis;` But he is looking for a solution to achieve multiline ellipsis.

Comment: His fiddle shows that he didn't used ellipsis property @HashemQolami

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works for single line truncating. I need to show the first two lines only, followed by an ellipsis if additional lines exist (see my example in the OP).

Comment: You're right, however `text-overflow: ellipsis;` doesn't work on multiline text.

Comment: @Ryan You might want to know that ["OP" stands for "Original Poster"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean) not the post itself :)

Comment: Your multiline method would also show an ellipsis if all text would be visible.