# How to truncate text, if there are more than three lines of text?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I am trying to limit the lines of text to three lines. If the user types in the text that are more than three lines, I want the text from the 4th line and below to be delete/truncated.

For example if the user types in the following:

```
<div class="example">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum 
dignissimos sint dolores
necessitatibus repellendus in nemo 
</div>
```

It should look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum 
dignissimos sint dolores...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/bjhvpf7q/27/

I am not sure what's the best approach to take to achieve this. I have tried using an ellipsis, but the issue I am running into is that, if there are more than three lines, it is hiding every line except line 1. I want it to hide only from line 4 and thereafter with the `...`

Comment: https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js does the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text)

Comment: Or, [Text overflow ellipsis on two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15909489/1016716) or [Pure CSS Ellipsis For Three or More Lines of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25448511/1016716)

Comment: Are you still need the answer, or the problem got solved

Comment: Hi @AnmolJuneja, the problem isn't fully  resolved, as the solution you suggested doesn't work on all browsers. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Yes, i can do but for whole solution js is needed. Is it ok if i use JS.

Comment: I am adding my solution, you can see and do let me know if it's works or not for you

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```css
.example:after {
    content: '...';
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left: 31px;
}
.example {
    width: 200px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
   height: 3.4em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum 
  dignissimos sint dolores
  necessitatibus repellendus in nemo 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using `-webkit-line-clamp`, but it is not supported by all browsers. It may also stop working in the future, but right now it seems to work pretty well:

```css
.example {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum 
dignissimos sint dolores
necessitatibus repellendus in nemo 
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text) is a very similar question with some more answers.

Comment: Yes, sadly this is not supported by all browsers. According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-line-clamp) there are quite a few who support this though. Unfortunately I don't know a clean css-only alternative aside from diverse hacks that I find quite unsatisfying. :(

Comment: Yup!, BTW there is alternative solution for this.

Comment: If you know a good solution why not just write another answer here? I am looking forward to see this solution.

Comment: @AnmolJuneja, could you please share the alternate solution. This current solution is not working on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to give inline line-height

I prefer this solution only when there is extremely need and client wants this.
Otherwise i personally do not use this, as by default we have truncate option.

So, its up to you.

This can be a solution for your problem.

Good thing is that it's responsive :)

```js
function countLines() {
  var el = document.getElementById('content');
  var divHeight = el.offsetHeight
  var lineHeight = parseInt(el.style.lineHeight);
  var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
  alert("Lines: " + lines);

  if (lines > 3) {
    $(el).addClass('truncate');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

p.truncate {
  position: relative;
  /* Height = Lineheight x No. of lines you want truncate  */
  height: calc(20px * 3);
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}

p.truncate:after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="countLines();">

  <h2>If more than 3 lines</h2>
  <p id="content" style="line-height: 20px">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit quidem sit dolores deleniti quibusdam odit, ratione nesciunt doloremque rem, consequuntur asperiores, reiciendis dolore quam ut! Pariatur repudiandae corporis voluptate rerum autem quaerat
    aut officiis incidunt, atque, beatae, ad laborum inventore
  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: It's help or not?? Please give your valuable feedback.