# Strip formatted text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested html that i wanna limit its content.

Is there any way??

there is an Example:

```html
<div id="description-list-31553" style="display: flow-root;">
    <p dir="ltr" style=""><span id="docs">
     <span ">Many people regularly put</span>
        <a href="https://www.realbuzz.com/challenges/run-a-marathon/">running a marathon</a>
        <span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">&nbsp;in their list of things to do before they die, so why not make this the year that you actually do it? </span></span></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><span><span ></span><span style="color: rgb(173, 0, 87);">Completing a marathon is a great personal achievement that requires months of dedication to training, and the exhilaration you’ll feel when crossing the line will certainly be something special</span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">. </span></span></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">If you’re already a marathon runner, then why not consider taking on some of the more extreme running events such as the Great Wall Marathon in China, the Antarctica Marathon, or even the Marathon des Sables run in the Sahara Desert?</span></span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p><h2 dir="ltr" ></h2>
</div>
```

i need just part of its content with keeping its formatting.

```html
<div id="description-list-31553" style="display: flow-root;">
    <p dir="ltr" style=""><span id="docs">
     <span ">Many people regularly put</span>
        <a href="https://www.realbuzz.com/challenges/run-a-marathon/">running a marathon</a>
        <span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">&nbsp;in their list of things to do before they die, so why not make this the year that you actually do it? </span></span></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><span><span ></span><span style="color: rgb(173, 0, 87);">Completing a marathon ...</span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">. </span></span></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></span></span><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p><h2 dir="ltr" ></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i confirm you want to hide the content if it's over a certain word count?

Comment: Very unclear of what you are actually asking for

Comment: two span with same id `docs-internal-guid-99f6eeab-2e5c-5920-b71e-6388c8f5a13d`?

Comment: @Christheoreo yes for example i just want to show 300 characters of its content but still shows up its formatting like the example in code snippet

Comment: I think the question it's clear, and I think that people have to read the question two times before downvoting, and not judge code with so mach anger. I'm more and more afraid to ask questions and give answers on stackoverflow

Comment: @Christheoreo yes, For example i wanna show just 300 characters so the others characters should hide or remove without removing any html code.(hide or remove just the content)

Comment: i dont need id in this case i just wanted to show more and more tag in order to show the problem. its fixed @don'tangryme

Comment: How did you populate the text? Did you enter the text manually or did you use JavaScript?

Comment: these are generated by Editor(Rich text) @Christheoreo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery you can try this plugin:
http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

### EDIT

Maybe this post can help you, you have to replace text with a substring of n given characters and add the three dots at the end

[Truncate text to fit in 3 lines and show three dots in end In Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972904/truncate-text-to-fit-in-3-lines-and-show-three-dots-in-end-in-html)

Comment: There's no jQuery tag nor jQuery in the example. Why do you think jQuery would be an option?

Comment: because many people (especially beginners)  uses jquery, and not everyone tags the posts with jquery, especially beginners