# How to display only 3 lines using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I've added CSS that truncate text to 3 lines, but after truncating, it repeats title after 3 dots.here is snapshot.

[image]

HTML

```
<p class="ccm-page-list-title">
<a href="/concrete5">Weight Plate Barbell Racking Calculator Imperial Units (Pounds) Weight Plate Barbell</a>
```

CSS

```
p.ccm-page-list-title {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    height: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

[Link of Page](http://exrx.net/concrete5/Store/low-volume-progressive-intensity-weight-training-1)

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css

Comment: @RoySonasish   That solution does not work with paragraph and anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add height property of paragraph in css

```css
p.ccm-page-list-title {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  
  height:48px;
}
```

Comment: After ellipsis (3 dots ), it still repeats the title.