# Display div in middle of post

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning twitter bootstrap 3, I am creating articles website.
Basically I store everything in mysql database.

My post have below structure

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Article Title -->
    <section><?php echo $row['article_title']; ?></section>
    <!-- Article Post -->
    <section><?php echo $row['article_details']; ?></section>
</div>
</div>
```

So here I have article post with lots of text. What I am trying to achieve is
to display another div in article post vertically aligned in middle of the post.

So e.g I have article post with 50 lines then I need to display div after 25 line.

Just checking is it possible with bootstrap?

Thank you

Comment: You could do a `for` loop using JavaScript that dynamically adds up all the rows, divides it by 2 (half) and then inject a `<div>` `.after()` the row.

Comment: Check this out, it might help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css