# CSS force text to two lines, even if it's shorter or longer (show empty line if shorter)

Tags: css

I want to force my text to always be two lines.

If it's longer than two lines then it should have "..." at the end.

If it's shorter, then the second line should be empty.

Can this be done with CSS only?

---

**I'm posting this again cause someone closed it as duplicate but linked a solution which isn't what I'm asking. This is the solution linked:**

[Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

**but it doesn't cover one of my cases (when the text is shorter than 2 lines)**

---

***EDIT***: Here's a JSFiddle showing how in my other case it doesn't work:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lukgzefy/

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo placeat earum, recusandae maiores unde et.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <h2>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectur amet adipiscing</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo placeat earum, recusandae maiores unde et.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <h2>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectur consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo placeat earum, recusandae maiores unde et.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first one should occupy 2 lines (and the second should be empty) but instead it only takes one, throwing the whole thing off.

Comment: line-clamp seems to leave the second line empty when the text fits in one for me?

Comment: I closed it. `line-clamp` works for the other case too.

Comment: Not working for me on Firefox :(

Comment: Tested on chrome, doesn't work either :/

Comment: @ManojKumar added a JSFiddle showing that it doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure if CSS can detect number of lines but you can try out other methods here: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ Combine JS + CSS. That is JS for detecting 2nd line and make it blank.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't set a `min-height` on the `h2` elements? Since you know the `font-size`, breakpoints, and expected content limits this could be a viable alternative.

Comment: Yes, or just the `height`.