# How to set a maximum length to the characters displayed in a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

```
 document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML=`
                <table id="emails-table" class="table table-hover">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                      <th>To</th>
                      <th>Subject</th>
                      <th>Text</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="table-body">
                  </tbody>
                </table>  
                `
    
                for(var i=0;i<emails.length;i++){
                  let row = document.createElement('tr');
                  let cols = '<td>' + emails[i].recipients + '</td><td>' + emails[i].subject + '</td><td style="width:50%;"> ' + emails[i].body + '</td>';
                  row.innerHTML = cols;
                  document.getElementById('table-body').appendChild(row);
                }
```

I'm creating an emails table with JS, and I would like to set a lenght limit to the email text, followed by "...", so that the text stands only in 1 row, and doesnt take 4 rows like in the image.

This is the table :

[image]

I tried by modify the `<td>` style in this:

```
<td style="width:50%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
```

but still doesnt works, this is what happen:
[image]

How can I fix this? (I would like that the email text is the 50% of tha table width). Thank you!

Comment: chekout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Comment: Add display:block to the above style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
str.substring(0,20)+"..."; }
```

It can solve your problem

Comment: Yes this is the easiest method way to solve, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #444; color: #fff">
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test@hotmail.it</td>
      <td>Test subject</td>
      <td style="width: 50%">
        <div style="display: flex">
        <span style="display: block; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;flex: 1; width: 10px">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't bother to have "To" and "Subject" the same size, you can use a combination of `style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;"` on the table (all columns will have the same width) and `colspan="2"` on the "Text" td. (you need the same colspans on the th too)

```html
<table id="emails-table" class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;" border="1">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th colspan="2">Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td>To</td>
      <td>Subject</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could have more "subdivisions" with colspan to adapt the size of "To" and "Subject" relatively (ex colspan `colspan="3"` on first td (width 3/8), `colspan="1"` on second (width 1/8) and `colspan="4"` on the last (width 4/8))

```html
<table id="emails-table" class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;" border="1">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">To</th>
      <th colspan="1">Subject</th>
      <th colspan="4">Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">To</td>
      <td colspan="1">Subject</td>
      <td colspan="4" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```