# Line Consistent For different resolution screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a section with 6 columns, each column has a header and a paragraph of 5 lines, my requirement is the paragraph should not exceed 5 lines at any resolutions. it should be maintained in 5 lines at any resolution. How to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Here is its [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924997/12425881) from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css) on Stack Overflow:

```css
.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original text:</h3>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
</div>


<h3>Short text:</h3>
<div class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
</div>
```