# Compacting very long text inside table row in html

Tags: html, css

I'm building html tables where some of the `<td>` can hold extremely long text. Can I wrap it like after 100 chars it has "..." and maybe on click it would reveal the whole text?

If possible I do like to keep this current style config and just add this feature.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #b4cfd8;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #b4cfd8;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #cff0fa;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>NServiceBus.MessageId</td>
      <td>aaa70f-246a-426c-8b76-ae4d00a381cc</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.StackTrace</td>
      <td>System.InvalidOperationException: very very very very very very long text very very very very very very long text very very very very very very long text very very very very very very long text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap the "super long text" inside a div then assign this styles to the div. `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

```css
  td div {
      white-space: nowrap; 
      width: 200px;       
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<table border>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div>
  lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long.
    </div>
</td>
  <td>
    <div>lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long.
    </div>
</td>    
  
</tr></table
```

#### Update

**Shrink on click**

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td div');
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener('click', () => {
    td.classList.toggle('shrink')
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  width:900px;
}  
td {
  width:50%
}
.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 200px;       
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
p.info {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="info">Click on text in a table cell to reduce text...</p>
<table border>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="">
        lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="">lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long. lorem ipsum super long.
      </div>
    </td>      
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: But is it possible to view all of it with a mouse click?

Comment: @Shahar Thank you for Comment. Yes it is possible and it could be done with Javascript. I updated my answer.

Comment: Much much appriciataion for your time and effort, thank you