# The post in a django app shows the whole content how can I change that?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working on a django website and the post I write is a story with 300 words for example and it shows all those 300 words on the home page

Is there a way I can make it show for example the first two lines of the story and then when people click on the details they can read the whole story

how can I achieve that?

(plus if you need to take a look at a specific part of my code please let me know cause I don´t know which part of it should I put here)

Comment: You can achieve that in 2 ways, you load the full story and hide it with CSS, then show it with JS on click (Nothing to do with python) or you can create routes on  django to retrieve a snippet of the story and show that, then on click you call a different route to get the whole story.

Comment: You can use a template filter `truncatewords` or `truncatechars`.

Comment: Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
if you want to use it on django templates
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Standalone answers": However essential the reference in this case, please also provide explanation on how this exactly solves the question. See [answer] for guidance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).