# Can I completely hide lines of text that are half cut off?

Tags: css

If I place a body of text into a container with a set height and hidden overflow, I will often end up with the final line that could fit being cut off. [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVFMy/) or image:

[image]

Is there a way to have that line not appear entirely rather than have this happen?

The scenario is that I have *columns which are a dynamic height* (100% of the parent height, which is 80% of the body height) containing blog-post text and I want to display a "read all" at the bottom if there is overflowing text (easy to determine). At the moment it just looks terrible with half rendered text sitting above it.

I can't remove the overflow as the columns need to end before the navigation, which sits at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspire you from the property `text-overflow` but you have to do it with JavaScript for multiples lines: http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/ (via [With CSS, use "..." for overflowed block of multi-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines))

Comment: Is there any solution that doesn't include jquery?

Answer (score 1):

see this is my code below

```
 <li style="color: Black; font-weight: bold; oveflow:hidden; line-height: 1.2em;height: 2.6em; ">Page Size
                    <select id="ddlOrderstoDisplay" style="width: 50px;">
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="150">150</option>
                    </select>               
                </li>
```

I Put these lines inside the tag it will work on all browser .Hope it will help for you

```
**overflow: hidden;
line-height: 1.2em;
height: 3.6em;**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase or decrease the `line-height`

according to your comfort

Comment: How would I dynamically set the appropriate `line-height`? Also, this would probably not look too great from the angle of consistency when there are 5 columns on-screen with different line-heights.

Comment: i am not getting.. why your are giving diffrent line-height ?? all 5 columns should have same line height

Comment: Ah true, though that still brings me to the problem of working out what the line-height should be in a dynamic space.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden`

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 92px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

just add 'column-width' attribute, it will work.
in your example it will column-width:100px