# Filling a box with text that exceeds its limit

Tags: html, css

I need to make a box that have a locked height and width. If the text content exceeds the height of the box, I'd would like it to automatically get shortened.

like this:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px; border:solid 1px #000;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque gravida augue, in luctus nibh feugiat et. In lacinia.
</div>
```

Comment: how should the text be shortenend?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS statement you're looking for is probably:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Which shortens the text with an ellipsis (…), [quirksmode.org has an example](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html).

For multi-line blocks, refer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines).

Comment: How does this work for multiple lines, I have never got it work for more than one line of text? Please see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RhXnv/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines for that.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible with just css alone, so the text-overflow option is no good as the above question is for multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back and while `text-overflow:ellipsis;` works great for single lined text for multiple lines where you want to restrict the height too I found the [ThreeDot](http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/) jquery plugin great for multi lined text with lots more options.

And also the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the **overflow** CSS property is for, you can see examples of it [on QuirksMode].[1](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html)

Without knowing how you want the text to be shortened can't give you any example's I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate the user input to a fixed length use the following
The example creates a textarea which limited the user input to 100 characters and also displays to the user remaining count.

Step 1 - Create Function

Insert the following code into the page head:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```

Step 2 - Create Text Area

Use the following code to create the form and text area (if necessary, change the name of the form and text area to suit your needs):

```
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);">
</textarea><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 100)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="100"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

if you wish to apply this to a text box instead just follow [this link](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html)