# Detect CSS text-overflow ellipsis with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/335/)

### CSS:

```
div{
    width:160px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I edited a fiddle created by someone else who meant to answer this question.

This solution works well, BUT in one case does not work correctly. If the text should be 100% of the box ellipsis, it is hiding the last few letters and adding "...". However, when you manipulate the CSS and remove the overflow statement, then the size fits.

So this way is not 100% reliable, but I need a 100% working one.

Does anyone have a proper solution?

Comment: Why would you remove the overflow?

Comment: just live in console, so you can see, that the text fits

Comment: first you need to NOT use `text-overflow` and measure the height, and then use it and measure the height, and if it's the same height, then don't use `text-overflow`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: there is a Class in javascript based on jQuery created by me called FancyTooltip. this has an option to look, if the text is cut by ellipsis. works well... until this happens, what i describe in my question

Comment: The title of your post indicates that you want to detect text-overflow - which has been answered.  What you describe in you question is a situation - but you aren't clear what you want to do about it. Are you looking for something else besides detecting when text-overflow happens?

Comment: i want to detect if the text in an element is cut by the css style text-overflow: ellipsis... that's what i asked for. the question is not answered, because the detection is not working on this specific situation. but i have exactly this case seen in the fiddle. as in words on js: if text in element has 3 dots on his end, make something. but as you can see in this fiddle, the ellipsed text is green and not red as expected

Comment: In the fiddle you link, the text is not overflowing in either div, so the function is correct.  There is no ellipse in your example, so there is nothing to detect. The div is wide enough so that the text will not overflow.

Comment: here you can see what i see: http://www.bilder-space.de/bild-fiddlepng-19784.htm

Comment: That looks like a browser issue.  Have you tried with other browsers?  Or is the environment locked to a specific browser?

Comment: Hmm.. i thought so 2... i will check this ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63913/discussion-between-mephiztopheles-and-whipdancer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to post my solution.

Now i'm using `el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth;` and it's working well.
Note that `el` in this case is not jquery wrapped.

Answer (score 6):

There can be a difference between how the page looks in the browser and the calculations used to determine if the text will overflow.  The box model doesn't always behave as we want.  That said, you can compare the innerwidth with the scrollwidth.

Here is a simple example that should correspond to the ellipse showing if true:

```
if ($('#div')[0].scrollWidth >  $('#div').innerWidth()) {
    //ellipse should be showing because the text is in overflow
}
```

I updated your fiddle and it works as I expect.  Your syntax for scrollwidth wasn't correct.

```
e.scrollWidth vs. $(e)[0].scrollWidth
```

Updated link to the new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/67upsqq8/1/

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/338/  as you can see, your answer dont work as well :(

Comment: Actually, in my browser your fiddle behaves as I expect.  Which is my point about the differences in how it looks vs. the calculations used to determine how the box model renders.

Comment: i dont know, if i understand, what you want to tell me, but can you tell me then, what i can do?  im using newest version of chrome

Comment: I linked to the wrong fiddle.  See if the correct link addresses your issue.

Comment: ya, but you edited the width :D  thats not that, what i can do in my project. so the problem is still not solved :(

Comment: At 160px width, there is no overflow - so no ellipse.  The overflow doesn't happen until the width is reduced to 158px.  At 160px width, the text is green and displays completely.

Comment: Note that this solutions wont work in all cases, this is due to the fact the this numbers are converted to integers using floor function