# How can I get all td elements with text-overflow: ellipsis where the text is truncate?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table where td style contains text-overflow: ellipsis; however I want to use jquery to get only tds where this style is neccessary, means all td that display (...).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtramp/w3g4y8px/), reworked for tables from an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629506/detect-css-text-overlow-ellipsis-with-jquery), using the answer from [mephiztopheles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4193654/mephiztopheles).

Using JQuery:

```
$("td").each( function() {

  if ( this.scrollWidth > this.clientWidth ) {

    $(this).addClass("overflowing");

  }

});
```