# How can I do text-overflow: ellipsis on two lines?

Tags: css

I have a container where the text may expand to two lines and it's 40px in height, with an 18px font size. When I do:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Then the dotted line shows correctly but it gets cut off on one line. When I do just the:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Then it correctly shows the 2 lines but there's no "..." at the end. How do I achieve this so it correctly uses both lines AND finishes with "..." on the second line?

Comment: white space can help in some cases http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bNxBxE br or pre

Comment: see my answer and code pen link I posted http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJQpWo

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Text overflow ellipsis on two lines, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines-is-it-possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert ellipsis (...) into HTML tag if content too wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide)

Comment: There are solutions to providing multiline ellipsis support at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536814/insert-ellipsis-into-html-tag-if-content-too-wide/19574664#comment50590706_19574664

Comment: display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;

is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `span` to the container, which will hold the text:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>text...</span>
</span>
```

Add this CSS:

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   background: white;   //or other color
}

.container:after {
  content: '...';       //the ellipsis
  position: absolute;   //positioned in bottom-right
  bottom: 0;            //...
  right: 0;             //...
  padding: 0 0.3em;     //give some separation from text
  background: inherit;  //same color as container
}

.container span:after {
  content: '\0000a0';   //a space
  position: absolute;   //to cover up ellipsis if needed
  width: 1000px;        //...
  z-index: 1;           //...
  background: white;    //must match container's color.  can't use inherit here.
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7863uw5/3/)

Resize the container, and you'll see that the ellipsis displays only as necessary.

Should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: background: white could become background: transparent. Furthermore, nice solution, mate.

Comment: @Tom, thanks.  I think you need to specify a background color.  Otherwise, the ellipsis may show unnecessarily.  See the first div at http://jsfiddle.net/j7863uw5/44/.

Comment: doesn't this depend just on the width?

Comment: Sorry, @UlisesCT, not sure I understand your question?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using `-webkit-line-clamp`. But a hack is needed. You need to set the height of the div such that it can accommodate only two lines.

See this codepen https://codepen.io/VamsiKaja/pen/xYZVzY

HTML file :

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et</p>
```

CSS file :

```
p {
    width:250px;  
    font-size:20px;
    margin:1em;
    height:50px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add my two cents. The closest pure CSS solution that works is the `-webkit-line-clamp` method but is limited to webkit browsers and is the remnant of an old flexbox implementation (which may be removed in the future).

Perhaps you should reconsider if you really require an ellipses on vertically overflowed text.

I suggest instead use a scroll-able text box instead. I believe this is the best solution because of these three reasons:

1. Works in every major browser
2. No css workarounds, hacks, or javascript involved
3. Communicates well to the user that text is cutoff but gives them the option to scroll through it if they wish - plus, users are already accustomed to vertical scroll bars

Here is sample code for a text box:

```
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;

  /* this is to preserve text containing new lines */
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

If I had to choose though, I would use a javascript solution along the lines of [Succint](https://github.com/micjamking/succinct) which deletes words after a certain amount and appends an ... at the end. This is great if you use React because you can implement all the code required inside the component as a function and if you need the original text you still have it as a props value.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me.

```
.cell {
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a pure css method base on -webkit-line-clamp:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {/*for test*/
    0% { width: 622px }
    50% { width: 311px }
    100% { width: 622px }
}
.ellipsis {
    max-height: 40px;/* h*n */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;

    -webkit-animation: ellipsis ease 5s infinite;/*for test*/
    /**
    overflow: visible;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .content {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    font-size: 50px;/* w */
    line-height: 20px;/* line-height h */
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;/* max row number n */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ellipsis .text {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
.ellipsis .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /**
    overflow: visible;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .overlay:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

    /**
    background: lightgreen;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .placeholder {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;/* h*n */

    /**
    background: lightblue;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .more {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;/* -h */
    left: -50px;/* -w */
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;/* width of the .more w */
    height: 20px;/* h */
    font-size: 14px;

    /**
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: orange;
    /**/
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsis'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='text'>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
            <div class='placeholder'></div>
            <div class='more'>...more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```