# Regex / Text Replace in Javascript .. add ellipses at last shown space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a very simple jquery plugin that clamps lines of an element to a set number of lines. Basically all it does is take the font size, the line height, and an argument passed to the function for max-lines, then it sets a maxheight and css-overflow to hidden.

To be clear, this clamps the actual element with the text, not a containing element.

I am wondering the best way to add an ellipsis to the last **shown** space. Should I actually truncate the text, then add an ellipsis via regex? If so, whats the best way to truncate characters that aren't shown?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. (Make your question MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just FYI this can be done in plain CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700438/519413