# Hide text after 2 lines

Tags: jquery, css

I have a snippet of code that hides text after 1 line. Is there a way of modifying this so it hides after 2 lines? It needs to responsive so setting a fixed height or width isn't an option.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/9t3Z5/3/

HTML

```
<div id="my_text" class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor // lots more text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#my_text {
    font-family:arial;
    color:#333;
    font-size:10px;
    width:80%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#read_more').click(function(){
    $('#my_text').toggleClass('ellipsis');
});
```

Comment: Looks like this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines

Comment: @itdoesntwork this relies on a fixed width/height

Comment: remove  "white-space" property and give some "height" to your "#my_text". But it will not show the truncated dots.

Comment: @Atula Thanks but setting a height isn't an option as I need a responsive solution, which is what makes this a little more complex. If I was able to set a height it would be very simple to implement.

Comment: ok, If you find some post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of the div by calculating the amount of lines. This can be done by, for example, div height = (line-height * 2)

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/9t3Z5/465/

```
var style = $('<style>.ellipsis { height: '+((parseInt($('.ellipsis').css('line-height')) * 2)+'px')+' }</style>');
$('html > head').append(style);
```

you will notice I have added the CSS as a rule as opposed to adding it to the element itself.