# Two line of text and overflow is dotted

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to display text in two line and overflow is dotted?
I can use

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But it show the text in one line. I need to show my text in two line and if overflow text then it should show dotted end.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working CSS solution for Chrome, Safari and Opera is:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

You can change 2 to any number. It will show X number of text and dots at the end

`line-clamp` is not supported by all browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp

Comment: Is there any solution for firefox??

Comment: As I know there is no elegant and pure CSS solution for FF. It can be something like this https://codepen.io/romanrudenko/pen/ymHFh

Comment: @VictorLeontyev You must have  also included the browser support for line-clamp.

Answer (score 0):

At `css` set `width` of element, `white-space` to `pre`

```css
div  {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>lines of 
breaks</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `White-space` Property and use a height of the element