# How to display 3 dots when text overflow div in height

Tags: html, css

How to display 3 dots when text overflow div in height. I've found an example how to do it when text overflows div in width

```
.cut-text { 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 160px; 
  height: 1.2em; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="cut-text">
I like big butts and I can not lie
</div>
```

But i can't find how to display ... when text overflows div in height. 
Any help much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text overflow ellipsis on two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve height vice text ellipsis through the **'-webkit-line-clamp'** css property. Use the number based on what line number you want the dots to appear.

```css
.cut-text { 
  width: 160px; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cut-text">
I like big butts and I can not lie I like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lieI like big butts and I can not lie
</div>
```